# Être reconnaissant envers / à quelqu'un

Tags: prépositions

> Je suis reconnaissante **envers** A.
>
> Je suis reconnaissante **à** A.

Est-ce qu'il y a une différence entre ces deux prépositions ? D'après ces deux dictionnaires ([1](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/reconnaissant)) ([2](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/reconnaissant)), non, mais j'ai l'impression que si.

Comment: Les deux dictionnaires vous disent que c'est le même sens (qui a (ou qui éprouve) de la gratitude (ou de la reconnaissance). Dans le TLFi, la définition (sur fond jaune) est applicable à tout ce qui suit avant la prochaine écriture sur fond jaune (évidemment une autre définition).

Comment: @LPH J'ai l'impression que avec _envers_ la phrase est plus solennelle, a plus de poid.

Comment: Une chose est sûre, même si « à » ne semble causer que peu d'ambigüité ou  n'en amorcer que peu dans ce contexte (par exemple : ils sont reconnaissants à un tel point que …), la préposition « envers », elle, marque la relation plus fortement et sans la moindre possibilité d'amorcer une ambiguité (ou presque : ils étaient reconnaissants envers et contre tout).

Comment: Ce qui est sûr, c'est que s'il s'agit de quelqu'un qui s'appelle vraiment *A*, il vaut mieux choisir *envers* ;-)